# Create password protected page, no registration

Tags: plugins, user-registration, password

I'm a Wordpress beginner and need a little help.
I would like to create a page on my website which is only available to customers. I would like only that page and subpages(?) to that page to be password protected. When one enters the customer page, I would like the customer to be required to enter a password to access anything else on that particular page. I would also like the customer to be able to browse other parts of the website without being logged out.

I do not want a registration form or anything like that, instead I would like to be able to create a user myself for the customer and send them the login information. It should not be possible to access the page if I have not created a user for that customer. However, after that I would like the customer to be able to change the password if needed, to a password that I do not have access to, if that is possible.

I can see that I could just create more users to my website and set them as "subscribers", but I feel like that might get out of hand if there are more than a few customers? So some sort of plugin is probably the best way, but the ones that I can find uses a registration form where anyone could just register. Do you have any suggestions on plugins and how to use it to achieve what I want?

Thank you for your help!!

EDIT: I realized I might have been unclear to what I want to achieve. What I want is to be able to create an individual "Account"-page, where a customer/client could log in and get access to. I want each client to get a unique user name and password, and preferably the client should be able to change that password without contacting me.  The problem is, I do not want a registration form or something like that, I just want to create a login to my existing clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a password protected page or a private page directly from your Admin panel in WordPress by clicking on Visibitly in the Publish panel in page edit mode and choosing which option you prefer.

To access password protected pages, you don't need a user, so regular unregistered site users can view the page, if you give them the password.

Comment: Thank you! However, that is not quite what I want. I would like the customer to get a user name and a unique password to access the page, not just one password for everyone. 
I'm not sure what it means to be a registered site user?

Comment: Ok... I am not sure whether I misunderstand again, but if what you want is to have certain registered users to be able to access a page, I kind of think that it is quite a complicated solution with passwords to the page. Instead, you should look into membership plugins. Many of them allow you to create different user roles and give access to certain pages only to certain users. There are also plugins resticting content by role, a quick search on Google returns many options.